# Constantly update map on new data

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a tracker app, which grabs data from server, so I wrote this request:

```
internal func updateOnlineTrack(for track: Track,
                            success: @escaping ((Track) -> Swift.Void),
                            failure: @escaping ((ServerRequestError?) -> Swift.Void)) {

let url = BaseURL.ver_2 + "tracks/points/new"
let parameters: Parameters = ["token" : ServerManager.manager.verification.token,
                              "data" : "\(track.id),\(track.sLastId)"]

Alamofire.request(url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
   
    switch response.result {
        
    case .success(let value):
        
        let responseJSON = JSON(value)
        print("NEW POINTS \n\(responseJSON)")
        
        if let points = responseJSON["\(track.id)"]["points"].arrayObject {
            
            for point in points {
                guard let newPoint = Track.Point(withResponseObject: point as? [AnyObject]) else { return }
                track.points?.append(newPoint)
            }
           track.sLastId = responseJSON["\(track.id)"]["last_id"].stringValue
        }
        
        success(track)
        
        
    case .failure(let error):
        
        failure(ServerRequestError(code: 0, message: error.localizedDescription))
        print(ServerRequestError(code: 0, message: error.localizedDescription))
    }
}
```

It basically grabs new data and appends it to a new so called "track"

Question is where should I call this method to constantly update my map with new data? Tried in viewDidLoad with a timer, but no luck

[image: No]

Picture is to illustrate what's going on. I have coordinates which I can convert to CLLocationCoordinates, but how to append it to existing route?

Comment: When the server request comes in and you call `success(track)`, just call a method right after that named something like `updateRoute()`, which is a regular, boring method in your view controller, that either removes all of the points from the map and reloads it with the new points or appends the new points to the map and refreshes it. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to delay the request in `viewDidAppear` or any further , as putting function call in `viewDidLoad` is the best during the time to load the data , the view will be rendered correctly for display so check the timer for `repeats:true` , and regarding append you can save the last point in the drawn path and hook it to the first one that you get from the response and add a new polyline to the map